# Divs wont align

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align 3 divs with the exact same height.  the farthest right two are the exact same are are fine, but the big one on the left is consistently above them.

I have taken into account the fact that the two smaller divs have a border width of 2px, but that didnt change anything.

I have even set a container div to be the exact height of the elements, but they are still not vertically aligned:

```
<div id='section_4_row_1'>
        <div id='double_wide_image'></div>
        <div class='section_4_module top'>
            <div class='section_4_module_icon'>
            </div>
            <div class='section_4_module_text'>
                <p class='text_1'>Job, Music</p>
                <p class='text_2'>Fields of gold</p>
                <p class='text_3'>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                <p class='text_4'>Continue reading...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='section_4_module top'>
            <div class='section_4_module_icon'>
            </div>
            <div class='section_4_module_text'>
                <p class='text_1'>Job, Music</p>
                <p class='text_2'>Fields of gold</p>
                <p class='text_3'>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
                <p class='text_4'>Continue reading...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

View on browser width at least 1350px

http://jsfiddle.net/51j6p5s8/

Answer (score 5):

Inline-block elements align to the baseline by default.

```
#section_4 .section_4_module {
  ...
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/51j6p5s8/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting them to remain the same size and align, setting your wrapping element to behave like a `table` and interior elements to behave as `table-cell` will ensure they are all the same height. Margins suffer in this method, but creative use of padding or empty table cells can bring that back.

See updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/51j6p5s8/2/

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is applying

```
float:left; 
margin-left:20px;
```

on all the block elements.